# print an auto generated number increasing everytime a bill is generated

Tags: java, jlabel, increment, auto-generate

i want to populate a jLabel on my bill jPanel with auto generated number which increments by one every time a bill is generated . can anyone one give me an idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any code and by populate i assume you mean update the label content
You can simply have something like this in the view class that contains the jlabel:

```
public void updateLabel(int generatedNumber){
   label.setText(String.valueOf(generatedNumber));
}
```

i hope this answers your question

Comment: i want to give each bill a serial number every time a bill is generated . i want to do that through a jLabel. i am sorry if i was not clear before . i am new to both java and this forum . the code u gave me is not doing anything to the jlabel. @Sohlowmawn

Comment: what generates the serial number? is it a class or what? @MohitJoshi

Comment: that's what i wanna know how to generate the serial no which increases every time a bill is generated. @ Sohlowmawn